# Creating C++ Extension Modules Using Boost.Python

Tags: python, c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, boost

I am currently trying to learn how to build extension modules so I can use C++ functions in my python scripts. I am using Pythong 2.7.9 32 bit.
Therefore, I installed Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 Express, using its C++ compiler to build the boost.python libraris. Then I added the ...\boost_1_58_0 directory to the include path of Visual Studio and the ...\boost_1_58_0\stage\lib to the library path.

After that, more or less following this [Tutorial](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Python_Programming/Extending_with_C%2B%2B), I create my hellomodule.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>


using namespace std;

void say_hello(char* name)
{
    cout << "Hello " << name << endl;
}


#include <boost\python\module.hpp>
#include  <boost\python\def.hpp>


using namespace boost::python;

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(hello)
{
    def("say_hello", say_hello);
}
```

Also, I create a python script called setup.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from setuptools import setup, Extension

setup(
    name="Hello",
    version = "1.0",
    ext_modules = [Extension("Hello", ["hellomodule.cpp"])
    ])
```

Then I place these 2 files in the same directory, open a command line, switch into the directory and run

```
python setup.py build
```

which gives me the following output:

```
running build
running build_ext
building 'Hello' extension
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\BIN\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox
/MD /W3 /GS- /DNDEBUG -ID:\Python\include -ID:\Python\PC /Tphellomodule.cpp /Fob
uild\temp.win32-2.7\Release\hellomodule.obj
hellomodule.cpp
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\INCLUDE\xlocale(342) : war
ning C4530: C++ exception handler used, but unwind semantics are not enabled. Sp
ecify /EHsc
D:\boost\boost_1_58_0\boost\python\module.hpp(8) : fatal error C1083: Cannot ope
n include file: 'boost/python/detail/prefix.hpp': No such file or directory
error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\\VC\\BIN\\c
l.exe' failed with exit status 2
```

I am totally lost here, the header file that cannot be found (prefix.hpp) exists in the mentioned directory. Anyone can tell me what I am missing here?

Comment: I have actually managed to get it working by creating a .dll file containing my c++ function using Visual Studio and import it into Python by using ctypes. But I would still like to find out what the problem is using the approach above.